# Facebook logout not working properly through the Facebook Connect iPhone API

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, ipad

I am executing the following code to logout of Facebook from my iPhone application:

```
if ([mFacebook isSessionValid]) {
    [mFacebook logout];
}
```

This code runs successfully and the delegate is called after this in which I am clearing the access token:

```
- (void)fbDidLogout 
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults removeObjectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults removeObjectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

But when I again log in to Facebook, it does not ask for username and password.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are those methods getting called or not?Where you have written code for your logout button?

Comment: yes these methods are getting called successfully but when i login i am not asked for username and password. It directly says that you are logging in as "SampleName".
Ideally it should ask for username and password.
If i uninstall the app then it asks for credentials.

Comment: Better if you can paste your all code for facebook integration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using FB mobile Login Dialog? In Facebook.m, add the following code to remove cookies at m.facebook.com domain.

```
- (void)invalidateSession {

   ...
    NSArray* facebookMCookies = [cookies cookiesForURL:
                                [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://m.facebook.com"]];

    for (NSHTTPCookie* cookie in facebookMCookies) {
        [cookies deleteCookie:cookie];
    }

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding these at the end of your fbDidLogout block:

```
mFacebook.accessToken = nil;
NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
for (cookie in [storage cookies])
{
    NSString* domainName = [cookie domain];
    NSRange domainRange = [domainName rangeOfString:@"facebook"];
    if(domainRange.length > 0)
    {
        [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
- (void) fbDidLogout {
    // Remove saved authorization information if it exists
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"]) {
        [defaults removeObjectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
        [defaults removeObjectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
        [defaults synchronize];
    }
}
```

Don't forget to create an instance for `facebook.h` in your AppDelegate.

Comment: Sorry but you are mentioning the same code that i have written in  my    question..

Comment: Your session is not getting Invalidated.That's the problem.Did you add  FBSessionDelegate in your ViewController?

Comment: actually when i first install the application i call the below code
[mFacebook authorize:mArrayFBPermissions];
this code first shows the login page in safari and then the permissions page. But if logout after login then it only opens the permissions page in safari.

Comment: Oh...then i think Your safari stores the session for facebook. If you try it without safari Auth, then you may get it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line to **fbDidLogout** method

```
[mFacebook invalidateSession];
```

This will surely make you logout from Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Try to log off from the Facebook application. It might just take the token from the Facebook application.